# SetObjectiveCompleted not working while completing the "Blood on the Ice" quest

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I completed the "Blood On The Ice" quest quite a while back and remember having a problem with the "Get assistance from Jorleif" part of the quest.

I completed the quest, but looking in the journal still marks that objective as incomplete:

[image]

I am not too savvy with the console commands so really I have been using the UESPWiki pages for help using them. With that said I tried the following:

```
SetObjectiveCompleted MS11 110 1
```

When opening the journal again the objective still appears incomplete.

How do I mark that objective as complete?

It's more of an annoyance if anything, but if it means restarting the quest then I could also do that, although I am not sure how and don't know what affect that would have as I just joined the storm cloaks and already have the strange amulet.

Answer (score 1):

Well I found a solution seeing as no one else replied yet.

I installed the `Unofficial Skyrim Patch v2.0.5a` and now the objective is lit up in the journal as to indicate completion.

[image]

I still wonder why `SetObjectiveComplete` had no effect, maybe the quest ID had changed or was not correct perhaps.

Answer (score -1):

When you find a page that says, "Beware the butcher" you find the woman that wants information. After that the rest of the quest is complete for awhile, but you will be led away from the real butcher.  The quest will be restarted, but is fairly simple after you talk to the wizard that is in prison. You go to the forge and wait, and when a woman is getting approached by a man with a dagger, kill him and the quest will be complete after you talk to the steward.

Comment: It's extremely hard to decipher what it is you're trying to say.  I would highly recommend investing a bit more effort into what you contribute, otherwise you will just gather downvotes.